# SSIS: How to check if a record DOESN'T exist in flat file but exists on the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, ssis

I am working on preparing an SSIS job where I am importing a .CVSV file to OLE DB destination (sql database). We are going to get these files on daily basis. The .CSV file contains records of doctors. Each row represents a doctor. Below image shows how I am able to do this successfully. No problems upto this point. [image]

***Here's what I need help with:***

If the doctor is no longer active we are going to get the same .CSV file without the record of him/her. How do I check to see if the record is not in .CSV file but it exists in SQL database? I need to update that doctor row in SQL database and update the **IsActive** field for that row to **false**.

Comment: We deal with this exact problem where I work, we tackle it with pure SQL and we try to avoid using SSIS like this.  We just import the table and then perform the required joins to our tracking table to determine if a care provider is new/updated/terminated.  For us, fewer SSIS deployments are better so we aim to put as much of the business logic in the database as we can.

Comment: Hey @saarrrr I am trying to do this  your way. I created a staging table where I am dumping the csv file. Now working on the merge statement.

Comment: Eric's pseudo code is correct, although you can also use a left join to achieve a single statement update on all fields you wish to capture change for. I would also recommend archiving the previous state of updated records, especially if you have different offices for credentialing and identity. They may compete for changes and knowing who changed what is important.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, this is psuedo-code.

```
SELECT DoctorID
FROM DrTable
where NOT EXISTS (select DoctorID from CSVTable where CSVTable.DoctorID=DrTable))
```

You could do the update in the same statement using:

```
UPDATE DrTable

Set IsActive = 0

WHERE Doctorid IN (   SELECT DoctorID
    FROM DrTable
    where NOT EXISTS (select DoctorID from CSVTable where CSVTable.DoctorID=DrTable)))
```

Comment: How would you implement this in ssis package ?

Comment: I wouldn't.  While it is likely possible, it will be both slower and more difficult.  A staging table is as above is the more usual method, because it leverages the RDBMS strengths.  Is there a reason you want to keep the entire process in SSIS?

Answer (score -1):

Apart from Eric's answer, you could also use the 'merge' function provided by SSIS by default.
You would have to make sure that your that your flat file source and the database are both of the same data type with respect to all the columns and they are both sorted over the key that you are using to join them.